# Laravel saving polymorphic model by request

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic relationship for `Likes` which can "like" both `Videos` and `Posts`. I am using an API endpoint to store the like.

However my `LikeController` looks like this

```
public function store(StoreLikeRequest $request)
{
    $video = Video::find($request->video);
    $result = (new StoreVideoLikeAction($video, $request))->handle();
    return $result;
}
```

My route is `/api/like/store/`

How can I change this function so that the `StoreLikeRequest` knows what Model (Post or Video) it is referring to automatically from my endpoint so that I can save it in the database? i.e. If I post a field called "post_ID" or "video_ID", or would a better option be to send an "id" field and a "type" (model) field to resolve this problem?

Or would I have to have multiple endpoints, i.e. `/api/video/{video}/like`? The same problem with this is that I would still need to work out what model we are currently using/saving in the `StoreLikeRequest`.

Ultimately, I wanted to avoid having a big if/switch statement based on what 'model type' is being sent in and I wondered if there is a simple 'laravel' way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you understand the best way to do it:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations